# How do I get all values of a column in sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

Let's say I make a table like so:

```
db.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
     job TEXT, 
     duration TEXT, 
     category TEXT, 
     expected_completion TEXT)
    """)
```

How would I get all of the values for the 'job' column? I'm aware that I could loop through each entry or use the pandas library, but I'm curious to know if there's a standard way to do this via SQLite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use regular SQL to retrieve your data:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("your_sqlite.db")  # connect to your DB
cursor = connection.cursor()  # get a cursor

cursor.execute("SELECT job FROM todos")  # execute a simple SQL select query
jobs = cursor.fetchall()  # get all the results from the above query
```

Beware that this will return a list of one-element tuples as we're only asking for one element in the `SELECT` query, if you want it as a raw list you can do it as:

```
jobs = [job[0] for job in cursor.execute("SELECT job FROM todos")]
```

Comment: The raw last snippet was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!